# How do i test if there is no internet and other network scenarios

Tags: android, kotlin

My app connects to the new York times api and need to test what happens if there is no internet on the device, if the api it self is not working or any other network issues that can happen.

Answer (score 0):

If testing by hand-  just turn on airplane mode.

If writing a test-  mock out your HTTP library to return a connection failure, then call the API.